# border-image driving me crazy

Tags: html, css

It seems I must have read every article and guide to using border-image that there is on the web, and have tried just about every suggestion possible, yet it still isn't displaying!  It's destined for a ul of class "navbox", and the full CSS for that element is below.

```
ul.navbar {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: #231F20;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    margin: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    right: 20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-image-source: url(C:\Users\imamadmad\Documents\Web Stuff\Locomotion Coffee\border.png);
    border-image-outset:4px;
        border-image-width:4px;
    border-image-slice:8;
    border-image-repeat:repeat;
}
```

I feel I have tried every possible combination of the border-image property, and even used both a .png and a .jpg version of the file, yet nothing displays.  I've even removed the other border styling completely, but replaced it when that didn't make the border-image appear as I still needed some sort of border! I'm not sure if it would have anything to do with the fact that I'm calling the entire document and all files associated with it through my computer rather than through the web, as I need to make a mock-up on my own computer before I can put it online.  However, everything else, including other images, are displaying just fine.  It is neither displaying in Chrome nor IE, and Firefox just doesn't want to show any CSS at all, so that's unhelpful.  I have tried adding the -webkit- etc. tags to the properties, but they made no difference either and besides, it shouldn't need it for the latest version of Chrome, which I'm running.

Please, can anyone help me!  While it's not vital to the design, it would really just make it that much easier on the eyes.

Comment: What is the expected output (how the border should look like) ?

Comment: Check the browser [compatibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

Comment: ur calling from your webserver to your pc. Try putting the image in the same folder as your html (in the webserver folder) and use ./border.png as url

Comment: @Benjamin Well, that's the exact CSS mark-up, and the UL itself doesn't contain any attributes apart from a class specifically so nothing can conflict with it.

Comment: @user3722165 Just tried that, but did nothing. Thanks for the advice though!  It shortened my call for another image considerably!

Comment: @Imamadmad It's because of the image-source in the css. I think it's not relative to your code directory. It's an absolute url, your links should be relative to the code directory. Check this fiddle, it works fine if you change source: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/301/

Comment: @Benjamin It's compatible with Chrome from version 16, and my current version number is 36.something according to the "About" page, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Hmm, well it seems from people's comments that it is the file location which is causing the problem, not the code itself.  Let me try calling it from elsewhere.

Comment: I've just uploaded the image to an online server (by sending it to myself on Facebook :P ) and called the image through there, and it's now working!  Well, it needs some tweaking, but it's actually showing!  Thanks all for all your help!  Couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: @Imamadmad if the image is in the html folder and u have a css folder u need to use ../ instead of ./ you see the ../ means going to the directory before the current directory of the file you are writing in ... so suppose your file is in website/css/style.css and the image is in website/image.jpg you put ../ not ./

Comment: @user3722165 Well the HTML and the CSS file and the image file were in the same folder, but never mind; I found a solution through uploading the image to the web and just getting it as I would a normal URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine. Check your image `url`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0er2u066/9/)**

```
ul {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: #231F20;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    margin: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    right: 20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-image-source: url(http://i46.tinypic.com/10gljba.jpg);
    border-image-outset:2px;
    border-image-width:4px;
    border-image-slice:8;
    border-image-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

**Edit : FIDDLE Updated**

Comment: I've called the image through a different rout, and it's now working.  Thanks for your help isolating the problem area!